# Remove Items from list with priority

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, linq

Lets suppose i have a list and i want to remove accoding to the condition that if priority item is there then remove all smaller priority items . for eg

```
Sortedarr[] =["world champion","Best performer","Best gold", "Best silver", "Best bronze", "regional"]
```

Conditions.

1. if gold is present i want every medal except silver and bronze.
2. if gold is not presnt but max silver is present then show only silver not bronze
3. if both silver and gold are not present then show bronze.

the array would always be sorted so always gold>siilver>bronze would be the order.

My implementation is working but i dont think its the optimised way of doing it.

```
    if(arr.Contains("Best gold")){
                sortedArr.RemoveAll(x => ((string)x) == "Best silver" 
                 || ((string)x) == "Best Bronze" );
            }
    if (sortedArr.Contains("Best silver")) {
                sortedArr.RemoveAll(x =>((string)x) == "Best bronze");
            }
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Group by medal type. Sort groups by priority. Select only the first (highest priority) group. Flatten out the the group contents.

Comment: But in your example, there are "regional" and "world champion" how about those? And if I have two "Best gold" how many "Best gold" you want to get?

Comment: Unique set of elements. And already sorted list.

Comment: @gouravm what is `sortedArr`?

Comment: So why not just get first element of array and remove others?

Comment: edited.- sorted arr or arr both are same

Answer (score 1):

If it comes to sorting, I would recommend implementing own comparer for string, so implementing interface `IComparer<string>`.

Below simply checks wether compared string contains either gold, silver or bronze and gives desired output based on score of a medal.

In case of a tie, we fallback to chosen comparer, here `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`.

In case if none of the compared strings contain any of a medals, then we also fallback to chosen comparison type.

```
public class MedalComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    private const string Gold = "gold";
    private const string Silver = "silver";
    private const string Bronze = "bronze";
    // Here you should put all medals with respctive score
    private static readonly Dictionary<int, string> Medals = new()
    {
        {1, Gold}, {2, Silver}, {3, Bronze},
    };

    private static readonly StringComparison StringComparison = StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
    private static readonly IComparer<string> _fallbackComparer = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;

    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        return IsTie(x, y)
            ? _fallbackComparer.Compare(x, y)
            : Evaluate(x, y) ?? _fallbackComparer.Compare(x, y);
    }

    private static bool IsTie(string x, string y)
    {
        return (x.Contains(Gold, StringComparison) && y.Contains(Gold, StringComparison)) ||
            (x.Contains(Silver, StringComparison) && y.Contains(Silver, StringComparison)) ||
            (x.Contains(Bronze, StringComparison) && y.Contains(Bronze, StringComparison));
    }

    private static int? Evaluate(string x, string y)
    {
        foreach (var medalKey in Medals.Keys.OrderBy(x => x))
        {
            if(x.Contains(Medals[medalKey], StringComparison))
            {
                return 1;
            }

            if (y.Contains(Medals[medalKey], StringComparison))
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Then you can pass it conveniently to `OrderBy` method as shown below:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var testData = new[]{ "world champion","Best performer","Best gold", "Best silver", "Best bronze", "regional"};

        var sorted = testData.OrderBy(x => x, new MedalComparer());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. but you can use [Array.IndexOf Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=net-7.0) to check item is present:

```
List<string> array =(new string[] {"world champion", "Best performer", "Best gold", "Best silver", "Best bronze", "regional"}).ToList();

if (array.IndexOf("Best gold") > 0) 
    array.RemoveAll(m=>m.Contains("Best silver") || m.Contains("Best bronze"));

else if (array.IndexOf("Best silver") > 0)
    array.RemoveAll(m => m.Contains("Best bronze"));
```

Comment: Contains itself checks if that is present, or not so additional indexOf function is of no use.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> array =(new string[] {"world champion", "Best performer", "Best gold", "Best silver", "Best bronze", "regional"});

    array.Contains("Best gold")  ? array.RemoveAll(x => ((string)x) == "Best silver" || ((string)x) == "Best Bronze" ) 
                                 : (array.Contains("Best silver") ?
                                  array.RemoveAll(x =>((string)x) == "Best bronze")
                                 : return array)
```

Comment: You just converted the logic in ternary. :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).